# Strange MVC Error Using GearHost

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

When I run my program on my local machine it works just fine. However, when I try to interact with my database via GearHost, I get this nugget of an error:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified.

Everywhere I have gone, the forums say it is a connection string error.

If that is the case here is my connection string:

```
<add name="GameStoreEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.GamesModel.csdl|res://*/Models.GamesModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.GamesModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\GameStore.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

If anyone has any idea about what is wrong with the connection string, I would appreciate your feedback.

Comment: I'm assuming GearHost is a hosting provider of some sort. The most obvious questions would be are you uploading your MDF file to the hosting provider?

Comment: The way GearHost works, when you make an empty site on there, it will ask you which Application Publishing File you want to choose from. Since I'm working on Visual Studio, I click the VisualStudio button and wait for the download to finish. I then get in my MVC project, right click the project name, and attempt to publish the site. It will ask me to import a publish profile and then establish a connection using the service url, site/application, user name (provided in GearHost publish page), password (ditto) and service url. Then I publish the file.

Answer (score 1):

GearHost does not seem to have support for LocalDB.

So you would have to create a database on their admin panel and use the credentials of the default user that is created to write your connection string. You could also create a new user for the database and use those credentials instead.

Either way your new connection string should be something like this

```
<add name="GameStoreEntities"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString="Data Source=DATABASEHOST;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;Integrated Security=False;User Id=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

- where you just replace the DATABASEHOST with the hostname for the database. You would see this at the bottom of the page after creating the database.
- You get the PASSWORD by clicking the uncover(eye) button after creating the database

---

- If you have data in the localDB that you want to sync to the database you have created on GearHost you can use the Data Comparison and Schema Comparison tools in Visual Studio to update the target database.